# É possivel utilizar contact form 7 com REST API do wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

É possivel utilizar contact form 7 com REST API do wordpress?
Alguma referencia para leitura ou implementação?
Obrigado!

Comment: O stackoverflow é para tirar dúvidas sobre programação, tratar de questões sobre programação e não pra lhe dar referências sobre plugins de wordpress...Você tem que chegar com títulos: `Problema ao utilizar contact form 7 com REST API do wordpress` aí você mostra o código do seu functions.php, até onde você foi...por exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Existe um plugin que você pode tentar utilizar:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-to-api/